# Access VBA Run-time error '2186' - This property isn't available in Design View

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

We are currently using Access as our back-end database handling a small amount of data records (<10,000). I am in the process of creating a log-in macro which checks whether a user has a valid log in, and based off that log-in he/she will have access to a particular set of forms. So essentially it is a permissions-based system.

```
Sub cmdDev_Click()
If DLookup("[AccessLevelID]", "tblUser", "[UserID] = " & Forms!frmLogin!cboUser) = 1 Then
     DoCmd.OpenForm "Finance_Form"
Else
    MsgBox "Sorry, you do not have the correct permissions required.", vbOKOnly
End If

End Sub
```

Whenever I run my macro, it continues to throw up the following error message "This property is not available in Design view."

I debugged the code and it highlighted the IF Statement. I double checked all the user fields and form references and they all check-out with no issues.
Could anyone suggest what could be the potential cause?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open your form, make sure it isn't opening in `acdesign` like so:

```
docmd.openform "Finance_Form", acnormal
```

If your combobox is actually a string format and not a number format then I would suggest something like so;

```
"[UserID] ='" & Forms!frmLogin.cboUser & "'"
```

Also, if your combobox has more than one column, which may be likely, you may have to state which column you'd like to reference. Column 0 is usually the bound column.  With this in mind see my example below where I have used `me` to reference the combobox  column as well. You may consider this if the click button is on the same form as the combobox.

```
Me.cboUser.Column(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to indicate the property of the cboUser:

```
Forms!frmLogin!cboUser!value
```